# How do i make div overflow over the other content at the bottom?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i have the following html code for the bootstrap collapse

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" style="margin-left:890px;width:444px;padding:0px;border:0px solid black;">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="padding:0px;">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" style="border:0px;width:442px;margin:0px;" data-parent="#accordion">
          <span style="float:left;">Month Calendar</span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" style="float:right"></span> 
        </button>    
    </div>
    <div id="demo" class="panel-collapse collapse in" style="border:0px solid black;padding:0px;">
      <div class="panel-body" style="padding:0px;">
          @Html.DevExpress().DateNavigator(Html.GetSchedulerSettings()).Bind(Model.Appointments, Model.Resources).GetHtml()
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this has a dev express control. when the page loads the navigator (this is a calendar) displays expanded and the context underneath it moves. So to prevent this i need to make the calendar overflow over the content. How do i make this calendar control overflow over the other?

here is an image to show whats happening

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should make the panel-default position: relative so that it's descendants are bound to it and then make the panel-collapse position: absolute to prevent it from affecting the rest of the flow.

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" style="margin-left:890px;width:444px;padding:0px;border:0px solid black;position:relative">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="padding:0px;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" style="border:0px;width:442px;margin:0px;" data-parent="#accordion">
      <span style="float:left;">Month Calendar</span>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" style="float:right"></span> 
    </button>    
</div>
<div id="demo" class="panel-collapse collapse in" style="border:0px solid black;padding:0px;position:absolute;top:100%;">
  <div class="panel-body" style="padding:0px;">
      @Html.DevExpress().DateNavigator(Html.GetSchedulerSettings()).Bind(Model.Appointments, Model.Resources).GetHtml()
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: You are using alot of inline styles, it is best to keep as much of styling as possible in css.

Comment: no luck still the control pushes the content i will attach a image to my original post

Comment: the calendar pushes the scehduler control to the bottom what i need to do is i need the calendar to drop on top of the schedualr like a overflow when i expand it

Comment: the calendar control goes behind the scheduler control (appointment sheet)

Comment: try adding z-index to the panel-collapse element

Comment: what is the best value for this z-index

Comment: A higher number should be a higher element. You can choose any number. The normal z-index is either 0 or 1 so 2 should do it. But you could have 10, 100, 999, whatever.